# How to orient towel holders on tile that is not installed straight

Tags: bathroom-fixtures, ceramic-tile

I was just about to install some towel holders on tile in the bathroom of our recently purchased house, and noticed that the tile is strangely not installed parallel to the floor and ceiling.  The tile lines slope 3/16" over the two feet of a towel holder, and almost 3/4" over the whole bathroom.  The slant of the tile is not really a problem in itself -- you would not notice with a casual glance.

But I wondered what was the best choice for aligning the towel holders -- level with the floor and ceiling, or aligned with the tile, at an 0.8% slope, or something in between.  It's not a technical question; more a matter of aesthetics or principle.  What would a pro do?

Comment: asking for an opinion is off topic here ... because there is no wrong answer   ... how would you choose the correct answer?

Comment: Think of the person who would be most critical of your work if (s)he found it unsatisfactory.   Tell that person you would very much value their opinion.  Do whatever they say.

Comment: I sort of agree that this is opinion, but another way of asking is, “what would a competent professional do?” (Answer: align with the tiles.)

Answer (score 2):

.8% won't be noticed by the eye

Align it with the tiles - those make the most definitive line

I installed a closet bar level in a closet that was way out of level and looking at it in relation to the closet made you feel sea sick.